# Learning guitar via staff

Tags: guitar, chords, notation

I am learning guitar from my tutor and he is teaching me to read notes on a staff. However when I search for guitar music on internet it comes like:

`A C♯m E Bm F♯m` etc.

How do I convert these to a staff or am I learning in the wrong manner?

Comment: With "staff" you mean "tablature" (or short: Tab) right?

Comment: I think he means standard notation?

Answer (score 11):

The stuff you are finding on the internet looks like chords.  It sounds like you are learning single notes in your guitar lessons.  If you want to play some songs you will need to learn some chords.  A chord is a group of notes ( more than two to be precise) strummed or played together where as a single note is, well, a single note.  I have a page of beginners chords on my site as well as a lesson on naming the notes on the guitar neck.  There are plenty of other sites out there with the same information.  If you wanted to convert the chords into staff you would need to work out the notes of the chords then stack them one on top of each other.  Can be a bit confusing if your new to reading music, so, for reading music I guess learning to read one note at a time is the right way to go.  However if you want to learn some songs tell your tutor.

Answer (score 0):

Learning to play guitar have been created with the beginner in mind. It is suggested that new guitarists begin at lesson one, spending at least one week learning the exercises and songs in that lesson before moving on. Learning to relax while playing guitar will help immeasurably, so be sure to have fun! [Ibanez guitar](http://www.fretmusic.co.uk/Ibanez_Electric_Guitars/) lesson picks up where lesson one left off. This second beginner lesson teaches scales, names of the open strings, minor chords, strumming patterns, and songs.

Answer (score 0):

You may have look at [Guitar Pro](http://www.guitar-pro.com/en/index.php)

You get lot of songs(format .gp*, where * can be 3, 4, 5, or 6) which have both staff notation as well as number method.